# Vbscript detect button in an new IE window

Tags: vbscript

I have a vbscript that opens an webpage, then clicks a button. That button opens a new popup webpage on a new window (notice: window not tab).

I want after my script press the button and open a new window, to detect and click the button called `id="pagesHeaderLikeButton"` in that new window, then close that window.

My script so far:

```
Set IE = createobject("internetexplorer.application") 
strURL = "website"

Do While True
IE.navigate strURL 
IE.Visible = true   
Do While (IE.Busy Or IE.READYSTATE <> 4)    
    WScript.Sleep 1000
Loop
    Set Popupbutton = IE.Document.GetElementsByClassName("single_like_button btn3-wrap")
    for each button in Popupbutton
       button.click
       WScript.Sleep 5000
    exit for
    objWindow.Quit
    WScript.Sleep 5000
next
Loop
```

Also to notice. I want to do it like this because the popup window allways will have a new url.

Comment: So there is noone who can help?

Comment: Search in all opened MSIE windows. You could find those and get their handles using `Shell.Application` property; here's an example in [my answer to another question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22911604/3439404). HTH

Comment: Hmm as far as I can see, your script detects if IE is opened. In my case,this script opens an website and clicks a button on that website. That button when is clicked, it will open a new IE window in where is this button that have this `id="pagesHeaderLikeButton"` and I want my script to press that button on that new IE window. I can't make the script to open directly that website and press the button, because the link will be generated random.

Comment: Yes, your script will open a new IE window... And _after that_ is the right time to search in _all_ opened MSIE windows  using `"shell.application"`. Of course, your criteria are different nevertheless the _approach_ is the same, isn't it?

Comment: Hmm I tryed something but no success... I can't get the button by ID. Your script is good but your script detects the url in the new opened window but I can't make the script to detect that button. Can you make a simpler version? The button is: `id="pagesHeaderLikeButton"`

Comment: This is what I want to do: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=11hJWyWT3qw

Comment: This is the first button: http://s13.postimg.org/ph408wbg7/image.jpg

Comment: This is the second button: http://s4.postimg.org/fg0zbsist/image.jpg

Comment: If I could see the new window is in _Mozilla Firefox_, not _MSIE_

Comment: It was an example. Is the same in IE. The website doesn't change HTML format if is opened from IE so the buttons have the same ID and Class.

Comment: This is what I wanted to make: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30717779/vbscript-to-detect-facebook-ie-window-press-like-and-close-the-window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
For Each wnd In CreateObject("Shell.Application").Windows
        If InStr(wnd.Name,"Internet") Then
            if InStr(wnd.Document.URL,"facebook.com") Then
                Set IE2 = wnd
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
Next
```

The above script will find any opened IE with the URL: facebook.com/*** and will set IE2 to be that opened IE.

So to press the button:

```
Set Butlike = IE2.Document.getElementsById("pagesHeaderLikeButton")
    For Each btn In Butlike
    button.click
Next
```