# VBScript to detect Facebook IE window, press Like and close the window

Tags: facebook, internet-explorer, vbscript

I tryed to make a script to detect the IE window that is opened on Facebook and hit the Like button.
Let's say I have 10 IE opened. Only one of them is on a page on Facebook.
I want my script to detect that IE window, click this button:

```
IE.Document.getElementById("pagesHeaderLikeButton")
```

(The above button is the Like button)

and close that IE window.

I tryed to get that IE window by:

```
For Each wnd In CreateObject("Shell.Application").Windows
        If InStr(1, wnd.FullName, "iexplore.exe", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
           Set IE = wnd
           Exit For
        End If
Next
```

But this will only set my VBscript to the first opened IE and it will not find the Facebook window.

I tryed this:

```
Dim objInstances, item
Set objInstances = CreateObject("Shell.Application").windows
For Each item In objInstances
    If Item.Name Like "*Internet*" And Item.document.URL Like "*facebook.com*" Then
        IE.Document.getElementById("pagesHeaderLikeButton").Click
    End If
Next
```

But I get "Sub or function not defined"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
For Each wnd In CreateObject("Shell.Application").Windows
        If InStr(wnd.Name,"Internet") Then
            if InStr(wnd.Document.URL,"facebook.com") Then
                Set IE2 = wnd
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
Next
```

So to press the button will be like this:

```
Set Butlike = IE2.Document.getElementsByTagName("button")
    For Each btn In Butlike
    If btn.type = "submit" Then btn.Click()
Next
```

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: This is the complete answer to the question.

Comment: @XmasterOfficial - because of the phrasing "So far", it sounds like an incomplete answer, or additional information to your question.  If this is the complete answer, you may want to slightly rephrase it.

Answer (score 2):

Next code snippet could help:

```
Set shApp = CreateObject( "shell.application")
With shApp
  For Each wnd In .Windows
      If InStr(1, wnd.FullName, "iexplore.exe", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        If InStr(1, wnd.document.URL, "facebook.com", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
          Wscript.Echo "THIS:"
        End If
        Wscript.Echo Left( wnd.document.URL, 70)
      End If
  Next
End With
```

**Output** example (with more `facebook.com` matches):

```
==>cscript D:\VB_scripts\SO\30717779a.vbs
http://www.msn.com/?ocid=iehp
THIS:
https://www.facebook.com/login.php?api_key=127760087237610&skip_api_lo
THIS:
https://www.facebook.com/literarnifestival1
THIS:
https://cs-cz.facebook.com/mgvsetin
http://www.bing.com/search?q=Xmaster+Official&qs=n&form=QBRE&pq=xmaste
http://www.bing.com/search?q=%22Xmaster+Official%22&qs=n&form=QBRE&pq=

==>
```

Comment: What if I want to click a button that have the id="pagesHeaderLikeButton"?

Comment: `shApp.Document.getElementById("pagesHeaderLikeButton").Click` is not working,

Answer (score 1):

The following code will search for open IE windows that have **"facebook.com"** in its URL and save them in a collection:

```
Dim getIE  As New Collection     
For Each Item In CreateObject("Shell.Application").Windows
            If Item.Name Like "*Internet*" And Item.document.URL Like "*facebook.com*" Then
                getIE.Add Item
            End If
Next
```

Then you can loop through the collection and do what you want with the IE items:

```
For Each itemIE In getIE
    itemIE.Document.getElementById("pagesHeaderLikeButton").Click ' For example
Next itemIE
```

Hope this does what you wanted! ;)

Comment: I get an end of statement at Dim ObjShellWindows As New SHDocVw.ShellWindows

Comment: I modified from: `Dim ObjShellWindows As New SHDocVw.ShellWindows` to `Dim ObjShellWindows` `Set ObjShellWindows = New SHDocVw.ShellWindows`

Comment: I also get a class not defined at: SHDocVw

Comment: Which version of Windows and Excel are you using? I edited the answer, please try it now.

Comment: Windows 8.1 Pro x64 and Excel 2013.

Comment: I also edited the question. Added something I tryed.

Comment: I get an "Expected end of statement" at `Dim getIE  As New Collection`

Comment: I tryed this: `Dim getIE
Set getIE = New Collection
For Each Item In CreateObject("Shell.Application").Windows
            If Item.Name Like "*Internet*" And Item.document.URL Like "*facebook.com*" Then
                getIE.Add Item
            End If
Next
For Each itemIE In getIE
    itemIE.Document.getElementById("pagesHeaderLikeButton").Click ' For example
Exit for
Next` But it says that: "Class not defined 'Collection'"

Comment: Try: `Dim getIE As Microsoft.VisualBasic.Collection() ` and then `Set getIE = New Microsoft.VisualBasic.Collection()`

Comment: Expected end of statement at: Dim getIE As Microsoft.VisualBasic.Collection()

Comment: Note: I hope this is for VBscript and not for Visual Basic since is a little difference between Visual Basic and VBscript. I don't even have Visual Basic installed.